# Sort deep multidimensional array or resulting JSON by key name

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort a pretty big multidimensional array by key names (**not values**), but I also need it to be as fast as possible.

Resulting array will be converted to JSON and saved in a file, so if there is a way do sort JSON by keys, thats all I need.

**I am effectively trying to find PHP equivalent of Pythons** `json.dumps(dict, sort_keys = True, indent = 4)` <- the sort_keys option.

---

I tried `uksort($array, 'strnatcasecmp');`, but that did not work at all, I also tried some other 'custom' solutions, but nothing I tried was fast and elegant enough.

Also, googling "*PHP deep sort multidimensional array by key/key name*" results in nothing. Every single question that has sort by key in title in end wants sort by value of specific key...

Is there any easy and fast way of doing this?

---

This is a simple example of such array

```
array(
    'common' => array(
        'zyu' => 'something',
        'gka' => 'something',
        'lfi' => 'something',
        'abc' => 'something',
    ),
    'data_result' => array(
        'doc' => array(
            66145 => array(
                'lfk' => 'something',
                'eks' => 'something',
                'abc' => 'something'
            ),            
            34154 => array(
                'lfk' => 'something',
                'eks' => 'something',
                'abc' => 'something'
            )
        ),
        'zus' => array(
            // some data
        ),
        'llo' => 'something',
        'abc' => 'something'
    ),
    'data_1' => array(
        // Array with lots of values and another arrays inside
    ),
    'post' => array(
        'id' => 15525,
        'time' => 156652363,
        'something' => 'something'
    )
);
```

This is what I need to get (as you can see, every single array key is sorted alphabetically):

```
array(
    'common' => array(
        'abc' => 'something',
        'gka' => 'something',
        'lfi' => 'something',
        'zyu' => 'something',
    ),
    'data_1' => array(
        // Array with lots of values and another arrays inside
    ),
    'data_result' => array(
        'abc' => 'something'
        'doc' => array(
            34154 => array(
                'abc' => 'something'
                'eks' => 'something',
                'lfk' => 'something',
            )
            66145 => array(
                'abc' => 'something'
                'eks' => 'something',
                'lfk' => 'something',
            ),            
        ),
        'llo' => 'something',
        'zus' => array(
            // some data
        ),
    ),
    'post' => array(
        'id' => 15525,
        'something' => 'something'
        'time' => 156652363,
    )
);
```

I am trying to avoid foreach loops and duplication of arrays, because the array is quite large (the resulting JSON file has between 5500 to 7000 lines (sometimes even a bit more)), and this operation would be done quite frequently and I do not want to overload the server just to make JSON files easily readable and debuggable by human.

---

Ps.: I am not creating those arrays, majority of them are read from binaries, which contain them in JSON format. I am only combining them to single array and doing some operations on them (adding some custom values etc.) and then saving it back as JSON.

If there is anything unclear (as its 3:35 am here, Im not at my peak), post a comment and I'll edit my question if necessary.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a recursive function calling [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) for each array item:

```
function ksort_recursive(array &$a) {
  ksort($a, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

  foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v)) {
      ksort_recursive($a[$k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is something I tried to avoid, as the execution of this function takes +- 0.01 seconds (from my tests, usually around `0.009605884552 seconds`) and IMO, that is a really long time plus I am not sure how big load it makes on the CPU. Is this the only possible/fastest way to do it?

Comment: Do you really need this on server side? If it is only for debugging, then consider sorting on client side, i.e. in JavaScript. There is always a better way, but I couldn't find it. AFAIK, the underlying quicksort algorithm is the best in general. If you really need to sort the arrays on server side, the best advice I can give is to implement the above-mentioned function in C (a PHP extension). This will eliminate the PHP function call overheads. Ah, if there is a lot of empty arrays, a check for emptiness will reduce some iterations: `if (is_array($v) && $v) { ksort_recursive($a[$k]); }`.

Comment: It is possible to implement this using `RecursiveArrayIterator`. It may save some memory, but I doubt it will be faster.

Comment: This has to be server side, in PHP. User uploads a file which is decompiled and server stores original binary and decompiled json files (website uses only json file, but users can download the binray file). I need it sorted, as sometimes the binary can be weirdly damaged and you have to manually go through decompiled version and find the issue. Also, there are almost no empty arrays. For me, the speed is as important as server load, but I wont build a rocket to save 0,01% of memory or gain 1 microsecond.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB, you can store unsorted JSON and schedule sorting for background job (a script running via _crontab_).

Comment: Yes thats also an option... I'll have to do some tests to see the difference in server load and speed, if its actually viable to do it with cron... I'll try to search for better option for a bit and give some time for others to answer, if I won't find anything better, I will accept your answer.